# How to hide a button on google sheets using google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with hiding buttons,
I'm using a sheet that have buttons that run different scrips but there is a big section of rows that is not always used, so I will like to hide that section of rows and buttons with a script,

Comment: Most likely it is not possible since buttons are images that are overlays, you can only hide/unhide columns or rows. Share sample/copy of your spreadsheet (remove sensitive data if any) so we can suggest alternate solutions if any.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide buttons, but you could replace the button with a checkbox, which can be hidden. Buttons are overlaid on top of the sheet, which tells me yours is most likely not covering any data anyway. Remove the button and insert a checkbox into its place. You can then add the following script to your sheet in order to hide the rows when you select the checkbox.

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Set sheet name here

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const value = range.getDisplayValue();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getColumn() != 3 || range.getRow() != 5 || value == "FALSE") return; //Change getColumn and getRow numbers to the location of your checkbox

  var hideStart = 2; //Row number of the first row you want to hide
  var hideEnd = 12;  //Row number of the last row you want to hide
      hideEnd = hideEnd-hideStart+1;

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName()).hideRows(hideStart, hideEnd);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName()).getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()).clearContent();
};
```

Make sure to pay attention to the comments and replace the necessary numbers. This solution will work on both mobile and desktop.

Below is a link with an example sheet to demonstrate how it works:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aKQKVcqSOAZv8eZJbChlAR6EyGfUFYQ17uc2lu3tFb0/edit?usp=sharing

Hope this helps! Let me know if something isn't working properly, or if you have any questions.